# Energy estimates (Evans PDE Chapter 6): Sobolev norm is controlled by an elliptic operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am looking at the energy estimates of 2nd-order elliptic PDE in Evans p.318.
In the following, everything follows, except that I cannot understand how the final line obtained. When I apply poincare inequality, I ended up with $$\beta\|u\|_{H_0^1}^2\le B[u,u].$$ 
[image]
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of forms of the Poincaré inequality says that for functions in $H^1_0$, the $L^2$ norm is bounded by a multiple of the $L^2$ norm of the gradient. Therefore, for $u\in H_0^1$, 
$$\|u\|_{H_0^1}^2 \le C_1\|Du\|_{L^2}^2 \tag{$*$}$$
At the end of page 318, the right hand side of $(*)$ is estimated by  $B[u,u]+C\|u\|_{L^2}^2$. Thus, 
$$\|u\|_{H_0^1}^2 \le C_2B[u,u] +C_3\|u\|_{L^2}^2  $$